# Cron Expression is not working as expected in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, job-scheduling, poller

Can anyone share a working sample in Spring Boot Application that works with cron expression in configuration file?

I've tried using below code snippet to schedule an external application. This works in exact 10 minutes gap for 5 times and then stops.

```
<int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" cron="0 0/10 * * * *" task-executor="commonThreadPoolTaskExecutor" />
```

Comment: hey @borchvm  please try with this example it may be helped to resolve this issue this repo := https://github.com/LalithK90/Springboot-Scheduling.git    this repo not use configuration XML file but I think that this would be helped

Comment: hi @LalithK90 I just edited the question, I think you wanted to ask Anumol, regards

Comment: @borchvm really sorry about that was my mistake